# Remap combining tilde to tilde (French keyboard on Mac Os X)

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The issue is pretty simple. Tildes have two forms:

- The combining tilde, which is a diacritic (ñ, ã).
- The "single" tilde, ~, notably used as a replacement for `$HOME`.

The French MacBook Pro keyboard uses the first one (`Option + n` or `Alt + n` - the option key is labelled Alt on a French keyboard). You have to press space to validate the single tilde (entering `Alt+n`then `space`will output `~` (without a space after). It is an issue in application like Vim, where ~ changes the case. Using the French keyboard it will change the case for two letters, which is very annoying. What is more, I never used the tilde as a diacritic since I first touch a computer keyboard.

This is why I would like to remap this key. This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/64072/cant-type-tilde-character-in-mac-os-x) says that it's possible with Ukulele, but I wanted to know:

1. Is it possible with KeyRemap4MacBook, which I also use?
2. Is there another easy way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find anything in http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html, but you could add a remapping yourself in private.xml. It's not possible with DefaultKeyBinding.dict because dead keys can't be reassigned.

Comment: The only viable option mentioned in this question was to create a new .keylayout with Ukelele: [How to disable inputing characters like ãâà by default in OS X? I just want to simply type ~^`](http://superuser.com/questions/191424/how-to-disable-inputing-characters-like-aaa-by-default-in-os-x-i-just-want-to-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KeyRemap4MacBook to automatically add a space when you press `Option+N`

The syntax for sending multiple keystrokes is like this [according to the manual](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en#basic-syntax):

```
<autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::N, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION,
  KeyCode::N, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,  KeyCode::SPACE
</autogen>
```

This code will produce a `~` without behaving like a dead key (technically it still is).

If this still messes with VIM or other programs, you can let KeyRemap4MacBook [switch input language to English on keydown](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/keyremap4macbook/oSTSMP0Iwqg/Xb5WAReyLowJ), send a tilde, and then switch back to your regular language.