# Where are default keyboard layouts located in macOS?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

As I understand, you can place custom keyboard layouts in `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` and `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` in MacOS, and they pop-up in the "Keyboard" section of Settings.

I want to observe, read, and edit one of the *default* keyboard layouts (Dvorak-Cmd-Qwerty). I expect it to be an XML file. Where is it located?

TL;DR: Where are default macOS keyboard layouts located?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) for this. Free, fully documented & won't screw up your original layouts.

Keyboard layouts are not in simple XML files, they're in bundles, & the default layouts are all together in one .bundle file in `/System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle` which SIP will not allow you to touch on Big Sur or later.

Custom layouts are, indeed in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` & that is where Ukelele will put your edited layouts.